# Array can't be coerced into Fixnum in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
sum.push(100)
sum.push(",")
sum.push(200)
allsum = sum.split(",")

while i < 2
    totalsum = totalsum + allsum[i]
    i = i+ 1
end
```

for this  i am getting the error as 
Array can't be coerced into Fixnum in ruby on rails
can anybody help me on this

Comment: can you call a split() on an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sum = [100, ",", 200]
i = 0
totalsum = 0

for i in 0..sum.length-1 do
  if sum[i].kind_of? Integer
    totalsum = totalsum + sum[i]
  end
end

puts totalsum
```

I am not sure about the Rails way. But is one of the solution using Ruby.

Comment: when I did sum[i][0] its working can you tell me why its 2 dimensional.